# Serialize to existing file and remove declaration

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have two classes which need to be in same xml file. The way the classes are done mean I'm having to serialize separately. Which I have managed to do. The first I do using TextWriter.

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
serializer.Serialize(writer, class, ns);
```

This works fine. Then I wanted to add another class to the file. So did same but added that I want to append not overwrite.

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
```

This adds the new class to end but also adds another declaration so my XML file reads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding"utf-8"?>
<dog>
...
</dog>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding"utf-8"?>
<cat>
...
</cat>
```

I've tried to use XmlWriter so I could use XmlWriterSettings then chose false for OmitXmlDeclaration but then it overrides the previous class I serialized.

Comment: You'll also need to emit a top-level element to contain the two object elements; it is an error for an XML document to have more than one top-level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML needs a root element to be valid XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding"utf-8"?>
<animals>
    <dog/>
    <cat/>
<animals>
```

You could create a `List<Animal>` and serialize it. But if you do not have the same superclass, you can try to create a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class AnimalCollection : IXmlSerializable
{
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Repeat for the Cat
        writer.WriteStartElement("Dog");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(TypeOf(Dog));
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, _dog);
                string value = stringWriter.ToString();
                writer.WriteRaw(value);
            }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

in the `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` you could use the generic serializer to serialize those objects then use the XmlWriter to write a startElement. endElement and include the serialized animal.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not valid XML, as it can only contain a single root element.

You could create a class to contain `dog` and `cat`, and serialize that.